# How to use C# Dll in python35

Tags: c#, python-3.x

I want to use a C# DLL in Python, and I want to create an instance of the C# class.
I have tried to below things:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"C:\MyProjects\Test")

import clr
clr.AddReference(r"Test.dll")

from Test import Test
```

but it is not working

Comment: Can you give an example of the source code of Test.dll?

Comment: what is error??

Comment: In python you better not use the name test? It may be confused with the original test package. Then, are namespace/assemblyname, classname, filename all Test? That would make it difficult to isolate the problem. You'd better name them differently.